# why the error from fetching data get passed to catch and return error get passed to then?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, es6-promise

## here i missed with the api end point so that it return an error and the catch handled it

```
const superAgent = require('superagent')
async function getImage() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(superAgent.get('https://dooooog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random'))
  })
}
getImage().then((res) => {
  console.log(res.body) // never called
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('couldnt fetch data')   // output ---> couldn't fetch data
})
```

## but when i returned an error the then handled it instead of catch

```
const superAgent = require('superagent')
async function getImage() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(new Error('some error here'))
  })
}
getImage().then((res) => {
  console.log(res.message) //output -----------> some error here
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('couldnt fetch data') //never called
})
```

i wish any one could help me to understand the problem

Comment: A promise can resolve to an error object. If you would throw the error then the catch function would be called.
MDN has some helpful explanations on Promises
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: @line-o i got the answer from MDN which is resolving a rejected promise will still result in a rejected promise. because get() will return a rejected promise and resolving a rejected promise will lead to a rejected promise which will call the catch block

Comment: while superagent.get will _throw_ an error when a non-ok status is returned from the server you are only _instantiating_ an Error object. Replace _new_ with _throw_ to see the difference.

Comment: or use reject(new Error("My Error Test"))